# URLs rewritten with IIS with 'URL Rewrite' get 404

Tags: javascript, flask, iis, url-rewriting

All

I'm working on Windows Server 2022 (EC2) and set *IIS*(10.0.20348.1) with *URL Rewrite* and *ARR*.
The server has web pages(html and JavaScript) and Flask application. JavaScript accesses Flask application route.

For instance, when JS accesses 'https://subdom.mydomain.com/myapp/login/', I expect URL is written to 'http://*private_ip*:5000/login/'.

``` Before: ``https://subdom.mydomain.com/myapp/login/ ```

`After:  http://`*`private_ip`*`:5000/login/`

The following inbound rule has been made, but JavaScript receives 404.

`Pattern: api(.*)`

`Rewrite URL: http://`*`private_ip`*`:5000{R:1}`

This is web.config and as you see, default document is 'login.html' and login.js access the Flask API route '/login/'.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="login.html" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <tracing>
            <traceFailedRequests>
                <remove path="*" />
            </traceFailedRequests>
        </tracing>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <remove name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" />
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="api(.*)" />
                    <conditions />
                    <serverVariables />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:5000{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

How can I resoleve the problem? The rewrite rule is invalid?

Your advice would be appreciated.

1. Checked [Log rewritten URL] option to know the URL after rewriting, but couldn't find any useful logging.
2. Looked into FaildReqLogFiles, but I don't think I found any useful information.
3. Access from the server local, Flask application works correctly via http://private_ip:5000/login/ .

Comment: `xxx.xx.xx.xxx` is not a private IP ... something like `192.168.1.127` is (that's MY private IP ... see how it's not a big secret)

Comment: https://halfblood.pro/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59 Mistake 3.

Comment: I appreciate your comments! I checked the link you gave. Sorry for the lack of explanation. ARR was installed. Do I need to set anything up other than installation?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your useful advices! The problem solved.

I referred to [The Very Common Mistakes When Using IIS URL Rewrite Module](https://halfblood.pro/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59), given from Lex Li-san.
I had already installed ARR with URL Rewrite but hadn't do any settings.
So I did as following:

1. Open IIS and select the server in the left pane 'Connection'.
2. Double-click [Application Request Routing Cache] and open it.
3. Click [Server Proxy Setting...] in the right pane.
4. Turn 'on' [Enable proxy] check-box. Leave the other items at their default settings.

I haven't changed 'URL Rewrite' settings as before.